# How to upload file on GAE with GWT?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload

I've been trying this for hours, so maybe a fresh set of eyes will help.

I'm trying to upload a file to the server using GWT (using UiBinder) on Google App Engine.  Following all the examples I can find, things *look* like they should work, but the server's 'post' method is showing 0 items uploaded.

Here's the client code:

**FormUploader.ui.xml:**

```
<g:FormPanel action="/formImageUploader" ui:field="formPanel">
    <g:VerticalPanel>
      <g:FileUpload ui:field="uploader"></g:FileUpload>
      <g:Button ui:field="submit">Submit</g:Button>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:FormPanel>
```

**FormUploader.java:**

```
 @UiField
  FormPanel formPanel;

  @UiField
  FileUpload uploader;

  @UiField
  Button submit;

 public FormUploader() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
    addSubmitHandlers();
  }

  private void addSubmitHandlers() {    
    formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        Core.log("Inside submitComplete");
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });
  }
```

**web.xml:**

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>formImageUploader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.server.FormImageUploader</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>formImageUploader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/formImageUploader</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**FormImageUploader.java:**

```
public class FormImageUploader extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.info("Request.getContentLength(): " + request.getContentLength());
    log.info("Content type: " + request.getContentType());

    log.info("Parm names: ");
    for (Object paramName : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
      log.info("__Param name: " + paramName.toString());
    }
    log.info("Attribtue names: ");
    Enumeration enu = request.getAttributeNames();
    while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
      log.info("__Attribute name: " + enu.nextElement().toString());
    }
    log.info("Header names: ");
    enu = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
      log.info("__Header name: " + enu.nextElement().toString());
    }
    resp.getWriter().println("Post Code has finished executing"); 
}
```

All this executes just fine, the client shows an alert box containing **Post Code has finished executing**, but I can't figure out how to get the content of the file I want to upload.

Here's the server side log:

```
Request.getContentLength(): 63
Content type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------194272772210834546661
Parm names:
Attribtue names:
__Attribute name: com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.APP_VERSION_REQUEST_ATTR
```

Can anyone help me see why I'm not seeing any files on the server after clicking "submit" on the client?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

Still can't figure out why I can't get the form data on the server.  I'm following [this example](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/java.html), and just trying to write the response out to the client, but the server is definitely not seeing any content from the client.

**Server code:**

```
try {
      log.info("Inside try block");
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
      log.info("created the servlet file upload");
      res.setContentType("text/plain");
      log.info("set the content type to text/plain");
      FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);
      log.info("Got the iterator for items");
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        log.info("__inside iterator.hasNext");
        FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
        log.info("__assigned the file item stream");
        InputStream stream = item.openStream();
        log.info("__opened said stream");
        if (item.isFormField()) {
          log.warning("Got a form field: " + item.getFieldName());
        } else {
          log.warning("Got an uploaded file: " + item.getFieldName() +
              ", name = " + item.getName());

          int len;
          byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
          while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            res.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
          }
          log.info("Done writing the input to the output stream");
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.severe("Exception; " + ex);
      throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
    log.info("Done parseInput3");
```

**Logs:**

```
Inside parseInput3
Inside try block
created the servlet file upload
set the content type to text/plain
Got the iterator for items
Done parseInput3
```

Again, it's definitely not able to iterate over the file items on the server... any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, GAE has a completely different way of uploading files (Blobs): 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Uploading_a_Blob

You need to supply the form's on the client with a Blobstore Upload URL (which times out) from the server, retrieved using:

```
blobstoreService.createUploadUrl('urlToRedirectToAfterUploadComplete')
```

After setting that upload URL on the form's action, the form will be submitted and the blobstore service will redirect to the supplied URL, which can then access the `BlobKey` of the object stored by Google.

So with this, I added the following `ChangeHandler` to my GWT `FileUpload`:

```
private void addChangeListener() {
    Core.log("Selected file: " + uploader.getFilename());
    uploader.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        MyApp.SERVICES.getUploadUrl(new SuccessAsyncCallback<String>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(String uploadUrl) {
            form.setAction(uploadUrl);
            form.submit();
            Core.log("Submitted form with upload url: " + uploadUrl);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Then in the servlet I have the GAE redirect to after uploads:

```
 @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
    // where 'uploader' is the name of the FileUploader (<input type='file'>) control on the client
    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("uploader");
    resp.getOutputStream().print(blobKeys.get(0).getKeyString());
  }
```

**Note!**

GAE will throw a OutOfMemory exception when trying to get the uploaded blob's value if the `FileUpload` control doesn't have a `name="whateveryouwantthenametobe"` attribute defined, even if you tell it (using UiBinder) that the id is `ui:field="nameofControl"`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the local file system - you should take a look at the [files api](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).

Comment: Can you give any advice for how to extract an uploaded file on GAE from the client?  That blobstore link just shows how to create a file and store it to the blobstore and doesn't show how to extract an uploaded file.